# Git: merge branch and all descendants in one command

Tags: git

Say I start on 'master', and checkout a new branch called 'child'. I then make some changes, commit them, then from child I make a new branch called 'grandchild'. I make some new changes again, and commit them. I repeat the process with 'great-grandchild' and so on.

```
       C3                      | great-grandchild
      /
     C2                        | grandchild
    /  
   C1                          | child
  /
 C0                            | master
```

Then I checkout master, make some changes, commit (C4). Say I want to merge 'master' with 'child'. Those changes will be reflected in 'child' (C5), but 'grandchild' and 'great-child' still be based on the old version of master.

```
       C3                      | great-grandchild
      /
     C2                        | grandchild
    /  
   C1-C5                       | child
  /  /
 C0-C4                         | master
```

Is it possible to merge the changes of master with 'child' AND all the descendants of 'child' in one command (so that 'grandchild' and 'great-grandchild' are automatically merged with master in a recursive manner)? Like this:

```
       C3-C7                      | great-grandchild
      /  /
     C2--C6                       | grandchild
    /  //
   C1---C5                        | child
  /  ///
 C0-C4-                           | master
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to make some kind of script for this, if you want to do it all in one command. Are you familiar with rebasing? Even if you rebased the descendant branches onto the new changes, there is no command (yet, as of Git version 2.0) that would do it all at once, you would need to repeat the `rebase` command for each descendant.

Similarly, you would probably just need to repeat the `merge` for each descendant to do what you want.